# Source IP for Services with Type=ClusterIP - does not work

Tags: kubernetes

The reality does not seem to match the documentation.

Here is the link - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip

Following the documentation I created the service:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get svc clusterip
NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
clusterip   ClusterIP   10.0.42.227   <none>        80/TCP    11m
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

And I have a pod from which I can ping the service:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k -n chip exec toolbox-78bd47cfc9-9pq8b -c toolbox -- wget -qO - 10.0.42.227 ; echo
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=10.254.2.73
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://10.0.42.227:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
host=10.0.42.227
l5d-client-id=default.chip.serviceaccount.identity.system-d-linkerd-control-plane.cluster.local
user-agent=Wget
BODY:
-no body in request-
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

According to the documentation the returned `client_address=10.254.2.73` should be that of the source pod. But that is not the case:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k -n chip get pod toolbox-78bd47cfc9-9pq8b -o wide
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
toolbox-78bd47cfc9-9pq8b   2/2     Running   0          28d   10.254.2.13   aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   <none>           <none>
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

The expected source IP is `10.254.2.13`. The actual value of `10.254.2.73` corresponds to the destination IP:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ k get pod source-ip-app-bdfcbcfbc-dxgzw -o wide
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
source-ip-app-bdfcbcfbc-dxgzw   2/2     Running   0          25m   10.254.2.73   aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   <none>           <none>
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Which contradicts the documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see that both pods have 2 containers. Are you running istio or have some service mesh running with sidecars? If so, that would be expected that the client IP would be that of the destination sidecar, which would be the same as the destination container.

Comment: @LudovicC - bingo. I already checked it and this is linkerd - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/122954#issuecomment-1910482077

Comment: @LudovicC - could you arrange your comment as an answer so that I could credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands show that there are more than 1 container defined in the pods. (`READY 2/2`).

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
toolbox-78bd47cfc9-9pq8b   2/2     Running   0          28d   10.254.2.13   aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   <none>           <none>

NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
toolbox-78bd47cfc9-9pq8b   2/2     Running   0          28d   10.254.2.13   aks-appnodepool1-28692080-vmss000000   <none>           <none>
```

This typically indicates that a sidecar was injected by some service mesh (e.g. Istio). Those usually intercept traffic, and forward it to the container.

If that is the case, the request would appear to come from the sidecar container, and have the same IP as the workload.